# 0-1 optimization with absolute value (equiv., with two inequalities)

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, integer-programming

The `bintprog` command from the Optimization Toolbox solves 0-1 programming problems with an inequality constraint and an optional equality constraint: Ax <= b where A is a matrix and b a column vector.

I have a problem of the form |Ax| <= b, or equivalently, -b <= Ax <= b. Is there a way to solve this sort of problem with Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy:

You have `|Ax| <= b`. This is equivalent to (as you yourself noted) to `-b <= Ax <= b`.
So, you have additional inequality constraints: `Ax <= b` **and** `-Ax <= b`.
Thus you have over all `AA = [ A ; -A ]` and `bb = [b;b]` defining your abs-value constraints:

```
x = bintprog( f, AA, bb );
```

Comment: Looks like you beat me to an identical answer by 43 seconds! Nice job. What's the etiquette here with two identical answer? Should I delete mine?

Comment: @raoulcousins: Please keep it!

Answer (score 2):

With size(A) = [n,m], your constraints are of the form

```
for each {i in 1..m}
  -b <= sum {j in 1..n} a_{ij} * x_{ij} <= b
```

this is the same as two sets of constraints

```
for each {i in 1..m}
  sum {j in 1..n} a_{ij} * x_{ij} <= b
  sum {j in 1..n} a_{ij} * x_{ij} >= -b
```

Since you have to write it in the form Ax <= b, it would look like

```
for each {i in 1..m}
  sum {j in 1..n} a_{ij} * x_{ij} <= b
  sum {j in 1..n} -a_{ij} * x_{ij} <= b
```

In MATLAB, given your original A and b, you can make these "doubled" constraint matrices with

```
A = [A; -A];
b = [b; b];
```

and solve your integer program with these new (A,b).